# Mac OSX My picture folder says 200 GB although it is empty

Tags: macos, mac, graphics

Mac OSX My picture folder says 200 GB although it is empty

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you booted into Safe Mode (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) and then restarted the Mac?

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: It is the same in Safe Mode. The disc space keeps going down as well. Now it doesn't say the pictures folder. Now it says the whole user library but there is no folder not even hidden that is this big.